# Should we can put multiple different object on a singlesurefaceview in ARCore?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

Should we can put multiple different objects on a singlesurefaceview in ARCore Android. And if possible than we can able to rotate that single particular object only and another all are remain as it is at same position.